# Site to Site VPN between Cisco C800 and Sonicwall

Tags: cisco, vpn, sonicwall

I would like to have Tunnel based (route based) vpn between Sonicwall with Public IP 1.2.3.4 and cisco c800 with dynamic IP. In case of dynamic VPN, i learnt that vpn mode would be aggressive mode instead of main mode.

IP address is: 
**Sonicwall**
WAN: 1.2.3.4
LAN: 172.38.54.0/24

**Cisco** 
WAN: 10.10.10.254/24 Gateway: 10.10.10.1/24 --> Cisco gets the IP from another WAN router.
LAN: 192.168.200.1/24

This is how i have configured Sonicwall.

[image]

[image]

[image]

What will be the steps to be followed in Cisco? Please help.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.